# Wordpress changing publish meta-box

Tags: wordpress, publish, meta-boxes

Is it possible to remove the "Visibility: Public Edit" option from the publish meta-box?
I can hide it with css fine but really need to to be removed from dom or not renders at all
otherwise people could use firebug to show it and change it.

cheers people :)

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have got is:

```
remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'post', 'normal' );
```

or you can try:

```
/** Private posts all the way down */
function force_type_private($post)
{
    if ($post['post_type'] == 'is_singular' && $post['post_status'] == 'publish')
    $post['post_status'] = 'private';
    return $post;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'force_type_private');
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just set all posts to private? I need to be able to allow admins/editors to set them to pubic but not authors..... tricky